# every time a button is pressed i want the textbox value to be changed , couldn't acheive this functionality for more than one buttons

Tags: javascript

```
<td><input type="button" name="btnOne" id="btnOne" value="5.50" onclick="setText5()"  /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="btnTwo" id="btnTwo" value="1.00" onclick="setText1()"  /><!--<a href="#">&pound; 1.00/a>--></td> 

<script>

    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('btnOne').addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('textbox1').value = document.getElementById('textbox1').value + document.getElementById('btnOne').value;
    });
}

    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('btnOne').addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('textbox1').value = document.getElementById('textbox1').value + document.getElementById('btnOne').value;
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your code is using 2 times the same id `btnOne`

Answer (score 1):

Add event listener for button with id "**btnTwo**". And don't use **onclick** as you have already added event listener for click event.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
<td><input type="button" name="btnOne" id="btnOne" value="5.50" /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="btnTwo" id="btnTwo" value="1.00" /><!--<a href="#">&pound; 1.00/a>--></td> 

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('btnOne').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('textbox1').value = document.getElementById('textbox1').value + document.getElementById('btnOne').value;
       });
       document.getElementById('btnTwo').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('textbox2').value =  document.getElementById('textbox2').value + document.getElementById('btnTwo').value;
       });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.innerHTML` on `btnOne` and changing the `input` tags to `button` tags and putting both event listeners in one `window.onload` and without `onclick` because you already have event listeners. Here:

```html
<div id="textbox1"></div>
<td>
    <button name="btnOne" id="btnOne">0.05</button>
</td>
<td>
    <button name="btnTwo" id="btnTwo">1.00</button>
    <!--<a href="#">&pound; 1.00/a>--></td>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('btnOne').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('textbox1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('textbox1').innerHTML + document.getElementById('btnOne').innerHTML;
        });



        document.getElementById('btnTwo').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('textbox1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('textbox1').innerHTML + document.getElementById('btnTwo').innerHTML;
        });
    }




</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add same Event listener to all buttons, then

document.getElementById('btnOne')

when you try to select element like this, you will get the first element with such id from dom tree and search will be stopped, you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className')
```

method, BUT! you will get an array of elements and `addEventListener` allows you to add one handler to one element, so you'll need cycle to add handler to all your buttons.

you can write something like

```
var buttonsArr = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
   for(var i = 0; i < buttonsArr.length; i++){
          [i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            //do something here
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's how you could do this in a sweep. This example assume all your buttons are used to add value to that given textbox. However, you could simply tweak the queryselector to meet your needs.

```
function addValue(e){
  var tb = document.querySelector("#textbox1"),
      val = e.target.getAttribute('value'),
      tbVal = tb.value;
  tb.value = parseInt(tbVal) + parseInt(val);
}

var btn = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]")
for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", addValue);
}
```

Quick explanation :

1) document.querySelectorAll allows you to get all elements that match a given selector. Selector works like CSS rules. For more info you might want to ask google.

2) Function called by an event receive an event object as parameter. An event contains a target element which points to the element that triggered the event.

3) element.getAttribute("value") allows you to get any attribute of an element. You could set an attribute named bollocs, you could still retrieve its value!